# Insert in the link table many to many in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have 3 tables

Operator
OperatorWarehouse
Warehouse

```
|   Operators   |     |   OperatorsWarehouses  |     |   Warehouses  |
|   OperatorID  |  -  |        OperatorID      |  -  |   WarehouseID |
|   EmployeeID  |     |        WarehouseID     |     |   Warehouse   |
```

So basically in my entity framework the "OperatorsWarehouses" table does not appear...

There is already data in the Warehouses table, I only need to insert in Operators and OperatorsWarehouses to make the relation.

This is my code

```
using (InventoryContext db = new InventoryContext ())
{
   Employee employee = new Employee();
   employee.EmployeeID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlOperators.SelectedValue);

   var operator = new Operator();
   operator.EmployeeID = employee.EmployeeID ;

   db.Operator.Add(operator);
   db.SaveChanges();                       
   ddlOperators.DataBind();
}
```

I already tried

```
operator.Warehouses.Add(new Warehouse());
```

But that is going to insert in the warehouses table and i don't want to do that, I want to insert only the operator on that table

Comment: query over the warehouses and then assign the corresponding operator to it .

Comment: Sorry could you give me an example? I don't know much about linq yet

Comment: or for the operator query the warehouses and add it to it's collection ,

Comment: var kettleWarehouse = db.Warehouses.find(f=>f.id==1);
operator.Warehouses.add(kettleWarehouse);
what you are doing is adding a new warehouse and ef does that for you ....

Comment: if you need to add an already existing warehouse to an operator you have to provide an existing id for it's warehouse , if the warehouse id is 0 , ef considers it as a new warehouse ...

Comment: Ah that's awesome, didn't know everything was automatic. I managed to do this with: " var warehouse = db.Warehouses.Find(1);  operator.Warehouse.Add(warehouse); it inserted in the middle table the operator and the existing warehouse

Comment: added an answer , if you think it's helpful you can accept it ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You Should Provide the Id for Warehouse of the Operator , if the Warehouse you are adding has 0 as its id then it's considered a new Warehouse.
you can add a dropdown list for the warehouses in your UI that the user selects once they are adding an operator.

```
using (InventoryContext db = new InventoryContext ())
 {
   Employee employee = new Employee();
   employee.EmployeeID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlOperators.SelectedValue);
   var wareHouseId = Convert.ToInt32(ddlWarehouses.SelectedValue);
   var operator = new Operator();
   operator.EmployeeID = employee.EmployeeID ;
   operator.Warehouses.add(new Warehouse(){Id=wareHouseId});
   db.Operator.Add(operator);

   db.SaveChanges();                       
   ddlOperators.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Just to inform that this doesn't work when adding the operator, it gives an exception about unable to insert original values or something. I tried with this instead             
-- var warehouse= db.Warehouse.Find(warehouseID); 
                        operator.Warehouse.Add(warehouse); --

Comment: this comes down to your app scenario , is your program a desktop app or a webapp ? 
based on the scenario you come to a connected and disconnected DbContext if it's disconnected you should use the attach method and attach the warehouse before adding it to the operator and calling savechanges.

Comment: it's a web app but i really didn't even know there was something like attach

Comment: no worries , read upon disconnected and connected situations and object graphs in ef.

Answer (score 1):

Add `[NotMapped]` in your defintion table :

Something like this

```
[NotMapped]
public List<Warehouse> Warehouses;
```

Answer (score 1):

Entity framework will hide the relationship table when it's a "pure" many to many relationship. So you won't be seing the **OperatorsWarehouses** table, it will be handled by EF.

To add relationships you just add entities to entities, so you can add an operator to a warehouse or you can add a warehouse to an operator.

In your specific case you'll need to add an **existing warehouse** to the operator, or an existing operator to the warehouse. Something like this:

```
 int whId = 1; //warehouse with id 1
 db.Warehouses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.WarehouseID ==
 whId ).Operators.Add(operator);
```

note: be careful about the FirstOrDefault which will return null if there's no warehouse with id 1